# finding <br> position in wysiwyg editor with window.getSelection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I am trying to develop a  wysiwyg editör. 
In the editör, i am trying to find the position of "br" when onkeydown function fire.

```
<p><b>1234</b><br><br>678</p>
```

When i locate cursor near 6 getting 678 with "oSelection.anchorNode.nodeValue".
When i locate cursot near "br" getting nothing.

i want to find before and after tag near cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:** After talking to ismail the question could be changed to: how to find out, whether the element before/after the cursor is a `<br>` tag. This can be achieved like this:

```
var selection = window.getSelection(),
    isBRBeforeCursor = IsBRBeforeCursor(selection),
    isBRAfterCursor = IsBRAfterCursor(selection);

function GetPreviousSibling(node) {
    if (node.previousSibling != null) {
        return node.previousSibling;
    } else if (node.parentNode != null) {
        return GetPreviousSibling(node.parentNode);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function GetNextSibling(node) {
    if (node.nextSibling != null) {
        return node.nextSibling;
    } else if (node.parentNode != null) {
        return GetNextSibling(node.parentNode);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function IsBRBeforeCursor(selection) {
    if(selection.anchorNode.nodeName === '#text') {
        if(selection.anchorOffset > 0) {
            // There is text before the cursor
            return false;
        } else {
            var previousSibling = GetPreviousSibling(selection.anchorNode);
            return previousSibling !== null && previousSibling.nodeName === 'BR';
        }
    } else {
        if(selection.anchorOffset > 0) {
            return selection.anchorNode.childNodes[selection.anchorOffset - 1].nodeName === 'BR';
        } else {
            var previousSibling = GetPreviousSibling(selection.anchorNode);
            return previousSibling !== null && previousSibling.nodeName === 'BR';
        }
    }
}

function IsBRAfterCursor(selection) {
    if(selection.anchorNode.nodeName === '#text') {
        if(selection.anchorOffset < selection.anchorNode.nodeValue.length) {
            // There is text after the cursor
            return false;
        } else {
            var nextSibling = GetNextSibling(selection.anchorNode);
            return nextSibling !== null && nextSibling.nodeName === 'BR';
        }
    } else {
        if(selection.anchorNode.childNodes.length > selection.anchorOffset) {
            return selection.anchorNode.childNodes[selection.anchorOffset].nodeName === 'BR';
        } else {
            var nextSibling = GetNextSibling(selection.anchorNode);
            return nextSibling !== null && nextSibling.nodeName === 'BR';
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** I think it is a bit tricky to always find the correct previous/next element, because the text is a node itself. So to get the previous/next element, you need to go a level up sometimes before looking left and right. Have a look at the following example:

```
<p><b>123</b><br><u><i><br>456</i></u><br></p>
```

1. Cursor is between 1 and 2.

   The next element is `<br>`, which is one level up and then to the right.
2. Cursor is between 4 and 5.

   The previous element is `<br>`, which is just one to the left.
   The next element is `<br>`, which is two levels up and then to the right.

If this is the case, you can find the previous/next element like this:

```
function getElementBeforeSelection() {
    var anchor = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
    while(anchor.previousSibling === null && anchor.nodeName != 'BODY') {
        anchor = anchor.parentNode;
    }

    return anchor.previousSibling;
}
```

---

**Original answer:** You can get to the surrounding elements with [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode), [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/Node.previousSibling) and [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling). So the tags before and after the cursor are:

```
var anchorNode = window.getSelection().anchorNode,
    before = anchorNode.previousSibling,
    after = anchorNode.nextSibling;
```

Comment: <u>456</u><br> cursor after 4 previousSibling and nextSibling is null

Comment: That's because the `456` is a text node, which is a child of the `<u>` node. So, in order to get the `<br>` you need to go one level up first: `window.getSelection().parentNode.nextSibling`.

Comment: bu it ll be more complicated tag ex:<u><b><i>456</i></b></u> how many up to i go?

Comment: You can go up until `nextSibling` is not null. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: ok i get. but when more than one br ex:<br><br><br><br> prev and next sibling cant be reached

Comment: Can you provide a longer example, please? Where is the cursor and which element are you searching for? Are you just searching for near `<br>` elements?